# XMLHttpRequest cannot load Origin http://m.snapbatch.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a subdomain website (mobile) that is trying to call a aspx page on my main domain website. There are no local files involved here (Domain to Domain). I am using jquery mobile and trying to make a ajax call. By looking around the web I know there will be a slim chance that someone will A.Understands my problem and B. Can answer it.

Once again. Making ajax call from jquery mobile site to domain site, getting error 
Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I added this and it did not work

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        $.support.cors = true;
    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your server needs to send this HTTP header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

Using [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php) (on the server) you would use this code:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.yourdomain.com');
```

or to allow requests from any client domain using PHP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

You can configure Apache to send this header for you in a configuration file:

http://harthur.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/configure-apache-to-accept-cross-site-xmlhttprequests-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Or to be more secure, the star should be substituted with your subdomain making the CORS request as that is a domain you trust.

Comment: Is there any example you can give me

Answer (score 2):

The properties you are changing have nothing to do with whether or not you can do CORS. They are simply flags that indicate if the current platform supports it. Changing them does nothing.

If you want to make cross-domain requests, the server you are requesting from must either return JSONP or return proper CORS headers.

Comment: Is there any example you can give me

Comment: @user516883 for which scenario? JSONP or CORS, and which server-side language? There are dozens of good tutorials on the interwebs for implementing each.

Comment: I really dont care, I just need something to go off of and maybe I can play around with it to get it to work the way I want to. First I just want it to work though. Thanks!

Comment: I have no clue what I am looking for, Should i type like jsonp c# or do you have good c# examples. I am new to this whole ajax requests cross-domain thing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, so I won't be of much help there. Sample search terms I would suggest: "JSONP with C#" or "JSONP" if you don't know what JSONP is to get a basic overview.

Answer (score 1):

I currently use nginx as a proxy to work around this issue in my local environments that need to make jquery ajax requests cross-domain.